# Call a function when debugging stops

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have some code that I run during onPause of an activity. I'd also like that code to run when I press stop in Android Studio, or press play and it automatically shuts down the activity before launching the new one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. The proper debugger is **transparent** to the code being controlled and the fact it's being stopped. stepped, paused or resumed should be 100% unnoticed by the code being tapped. Otherwise it would simply make rather little sense for 99,9% of cases.

You may however plant some code that will i.e. ensure that debugger is connected, like methods from [Debug](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html) class, which often come handy as `waitForDebugger()` or `isDebuggerConnected()`. You can then ensure this code is stripped from release build with use of ProGuard.

Answer (score 0):

The more similar thing to what you're asking is to detect if the debugger is attached, but as @Marcin-Orlowski says, aside from this debugger should be transparent.

This will return if debugger is attached:

```
android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected()
```